# How can I use MQTT long term in IoT Core?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, mqtt, iot

So first of all, what I really want to achieve: I want to know when an IoT device has stopped working (i.e. lost connection, shut down, basically it's not longer talking to IoT Core). I can't seem to find an implementation for this on GCP.

I have a raspberry pi as my IoT device, I have configured it on IoT core and somewhere I read that since this is not implemented a way to solve it is to create a logging sink which activates a cloud function whenever there is a CONNECT/DISCONNECT log. This would serve my purpose and I have implemented this sink and cloud function to alert me.

I have been following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge) on connecting to MQTT. However, the way the explain it, they set it up such that whenever the expiration time on the JWT is exceeded, they disconnect the client and create a new one to re-new the JWT. This would make it such that I am going to be alerted of connection/disconnection whenever this client needs to be renewed. So I won't be able to differentiate of a real issue from renewals of the MQTT client.

In the same guide, I see that they mention MQTT long term or LTS, and they claim that this way you can set up the client once and communicate continuously through it for the supported time which it says its until 2030. This seems to be what I really want, but I have not been able to connect this way and they don't explain it other than saying the hostname should be `mqtt.2030.ltsapis.goog` and to use a primary and backup certificates which are different from the complete root CA from the first method.

I tried using basically the same process for setting up the client:

```
    client = mqtt.Client(client_id=client_id)

    # With Google Cloud IoT Core, the username field is ignored, and the
    # password field is used to transmit a JWT to authorize the device.
    client.username_pw_set(
        username='unused',
        password=create_jwt(project_id, private_key_file, algorithm))

    # Enable SSL/TLS support.
    client.tls_set(ca_certs=ca_certs, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
```

but changing the hostname and giving it the primary cert where I would give it the complete ca_certs, but it won't accept it and I am not sure how to do it otherwise with primary and backup certifications. I am looking at the documentation on tls_set, but I don't see where these would go or how they differ from the complete ca certs. I haven't seen any other examples outside of this guide.

I am hoping to be able to connect to this MQTT LTS so that I can maintain the connection without having to constantly renew the client.

Answer (score 2):

The long term MQTT domain lets you use the LTS *configuration* for a long period of time, not the connection.

As you mention, for your use case the solution would be to activate and use [device logs](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/device-logs). One of the events is triggered when a [device disconnects](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/device-logs#list_of_logged_device_events) from IoT Core, and you can use that event to trigger an alert.

Keep in mind that the [time limits](https://cloud.google.com/iot/quotas#time_limits) for the connection are set for security purposes, and the client should renew the connection.

Comment: I see, that's what I was afraid of. The way that you mention, which I have now will tell me every time there's a connect or a disconnect which happens organically as the client renews the connection. That doesn't quite let me know a device has not been connecting back.


I am surprised there's no implementation of this as far as I can tell. How do people keep track of large fleets of IoT devices, in the case that one of them drops out for a while for whatever reason?

Comment: IoT Core knows the status of the devices, so an [API call](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiot/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries.devices#Device) can give you, for example 'lastEventTime' that you can use to know if the device has communicated with IoT Core when it should have. If you want to automate it, call the API from a Cloud Function that is triggered when a DISCONNECT event happens in the device log. Or, depending on how frequently you are expecting telemetry, you can just use Cloud Scheduler.

Comment: Interesting, I think that could be a solution. I guess if the mqtt bridge is getting renewed I could have it wait for a while when a DISCONNECT event happens and see if it came back, if it didn't then I can consider it a problem and alert to it.